# Enforcing single instances from the metamodel

Tags: metaprogramming, raku, rakudo

I know that it's way easier to ensure single instances from the class level, and that there's the excellent [`Staticish`](https://github.com/jonathanstowe/Staticish) module from Jonathan Stowe that does the same by using roles, but I just want to try and understand a bit better how the [class higher order working](https://docs.raku.org/type/Metamodel::ClassHOW) can be handled, mainly for a FOSDEM talk. I could think of several ways of doing to at the metamodel level, but eventually this is what I came up with:

```
my class MetamodelX::Singleton is Metamodel::ClassHOW {

    my \instance = Mu;

    method compose(Mu \type) {
        my &callsame := CORE::<&callsame>; # Workaround for RT #127858
        self.method_table(type)<new>.wrap: -> \SELF, | {
            unless instance.defined { instance = SELF };
            callsame();
        };
    }
}

my package EXPORTHOW {
    package DECLARE {
        constant singleton = MetamodelX::Singleton;
    }
}
```

> Mainly ripped from the [`OO::Monitors`](https://github.com/jnthn/oo-monitors/blob/1e4d81ab41c52bd6cfa3f793d1405956843a2f3d/lib/OO/Monitors.pm6) code, written as far as I understand it, by JJ Atria and Jonathan Worthington)

Main rationale is trying to wrap the building submethod, or somehow whatever tries to create a new instance of the object. This, however (as well as the same with `BUILD` and `BUILDALL`, close to the original), fails with:

```
No such method 'wrap' for invocant of type 'Any'.  Did you mean any of
these: 'Map', 'WHAT', 'grep', 'map'?
```

So quite clearly I'm not getting what these do, or for that matter the whole HOW concept. So any idea what might be failing here, or any other way to override the building of the object at the metamodel level to be able to do as intended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few misunderstandings in this attempt.

1. There is one instance of a meta-class per type. Thus if we want to allow a given type to only be instantiated once, the correct scoping is an attribute in the meta-class, not a `my`. A `my` would mean there's one global object no matter which type we create.
2. The `compose` method, when subclassing `ClassHOW`, should always call back up to the base `compose` method (which can be done using `callsame`). Otherwise, the class will not be composed.
3. The `method_table` method returns the table of methods for this *exact* type. However, most classes won't have a `new` method. Rather, they will inherit the default one. If we wrap *that*, however, we'd be having a very global effect.

While `new` is relatively common to override to change the interface to construction, the `bless` method - which `new` calls after doing any mapping work - is not something we'd expect language users to be overriding. So one way we could proceed is to just try installing a `bless` method that does the required logic. (We could also work with `new`, but really we'd need to check if there was one in this class, wrap it if so, and add a copy of the default one that we then wrap if not, which is a bit more effort.)

Here's a solution that works:

```
my class MetamodelX::Singleton is Metamodel::ClassHOW {
    has $!instance;

    method compose(Mu \type) {
        self.add_method(type, 'bless', -> \SELF, |c {
            without $!instance {
                $!instance := SELF.Mu::bless(|c);
            }
            $!instance
        });
        callsame();
    }
}

my package EXPORTHOW {
    package DECLARE {
        constant singleton = MetamodelX::Singleton;
    }
}
```

Note that we can't use `callsame` inside of the code we add for `bless` because it's not actually a `method`. We could instead write it to use an `anon method`, but then we have the problem that the method has its own idea of `self`, and so we end up having to save the meta-class `self` and arrange some other means to access `$!instance`.

Finally, an example of it in action:

```
use Singleton;

singleton Counter {
    has $.x;
    method inc() { $!x++ }
}

my $c1 = Counter.new;
$c1.inc;

my $c2 = Counter.new; # Gets same instance as in $c1
$c1.inc;
$c2.inc;

say $c1.x; # 3 
say $c2.x; # 3
```

Comment: If I got this correctly, what you're doing then by creating a class-specific `bless` is the generation of one for the class when the rest of the class is composed. When the BUILDPLAN is created in https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Metamodel/ClassHOW.nqp#L213, it will not need to add that one, is that correct?

Comment: @jjmerelo No, there is never a generated `bless`, everything inherits the one in `Mu`  - unless it defines one, which I've pretty much never seen. You're maybe thinking of `BUILDALL`, which is generated.